# Which standard Java collections are remove-safe during iteration?

Tags: java

Using `for(Type x:collection){...}` which widely used collection types make removing `x` safe during iteration?

And is there a technical term for this to look out for in the JavaDocs?

**Clarification:**

I initially only asked about using the for-each syntax `for(Type x:collection){...}`. However a more complete answer would describe this style AND using a normal Iterator-based loop where there are differences... the question is more about which standard Collections allow me to remove elements during iteration, AND how to perform the iteration to allow this.

Comment: Do you mean for-each iteration or `Iterator` iteration?

Comment: @Tharwen those are the same...

Comment: @jjm: For the purposes for this question, they are *very* different.

Comment: @jjm: not quite - using for-each you don't have access to the iterator object and its remove() method, which is very relevant here.

Comment: Ah, very true.  So yes, calling collection.remove is never safe during iteration afaik, but if you're using an iterator instead of for each, you can often use iterator.remove()

Comment: @Tharwen primarily as in the example given but answers covering both (or even iterating by index) are welcome.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, you'd wonder why j.u.Enumerator was virtually deprecated, just to introduce the iterator and recommend for-each now

Comment: @bestsss: The Enumeration interface did not have the remove() method, and you cannot add methods to a published interface because it would break all existing implementations

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, I didnt mean that, the Enumeration has been out of favor even though `for-each` doesn't ever offer a construct to remove the currently active element. My point is that for-each should work for Enumeration just as well.

Comment: @bestsss: it doesn't work for Iterator either, it works on Iterable, which has a method that returns an Iterator. And Enumeration was already pseudo-deprecated in Java 1.2, while the for-each loop was introduced in Java 5 / 1.5 - by that time, Enumeration had become truly irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, sure it was for Iterable that was put in java.lang (but referring java.util), that would have been no issue to have Enumerable added just as well. Point is that Enumeration has been out of favor just to add the `remove()` method that was made inaccessible in `for-each`. Btw there have are public interfaces that have methods extra introduced  over time.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, the entire `java.sql.` you may argue it's an spi alike but even having a simple wrapper around sql stuff require heavy refactoring with the changes. iirc, `javax.naming.Context` got some extra methods in 1.3 as well.

Answer (score 5):

One such collection is [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). Other collections in the `java.util.concurrent` package share this feature.

The fact that their iterators never throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` is a side-effect of the copy-on-write semantics of this class: every time you modify it, the underlying array will be copied. This is done to allow fast concurrent access to often-read but rarely-modified lists.

The JavaDoc explains it like this (emphasis mine):

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and **the iterator is guaranteed not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`**.

In addition to the high costs of updates this implementation has some further drawbacks:

> The iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created. Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (`remove`, `set`, and `add`) are not supported. These methods throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Note that those collections are *not* meant to be utility to allow "easy" looping-and-removal, but are *specialized* collections for use in high-concurrency situations where many threads need concurrent access to data that can still change (but usually changes rarely). **Do not** simply replace every `ArrayList` with a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: Some java.concurrent.* collections are too.

Comment: So are you saying _none_ of the 'vanilla' Collections support this?

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList iterator **does not** support remove

Comment: @John, the ones w/ enumerator can do that, be tricky and use it :P

Comment: @John: no, they don't. Because what you're asking for is not a "feature". Throwing a `CME` *is a feature*. It **helps** you find out situations where you're using a collection in an undefined way.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of the thumb: Anything w/ Concurrent or Blocking in its name, aka. `ConcurrentLinkedList`, `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, `LinkedBlockingDeque`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, etc.
The keySet(), values() of ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap and so on.
Most java.util.concurrent is `ConcurrentModificationException` and that is good.

COWArrayList is usually useful for either smaller sized collections or rarely modified ones... and you should avoid the explicit `set` method.

One important note: using iterator.remove should be always  favored to Collection.remove (except CHM.entrySet() which is impl. in a buggy way) [*when availble*, COWArrayList iterator does not support remove]. All non-random access structures will benefit from not having to look up the element which can be O(n).

Overall `ConcurrentModificationException` was a half-baked idea and its impl. involves some side effects, incl. preventing hardware-transaction-memory to operate. It imposes extra performance costs that are rarely needed. `HashMap` has a terrible impl. w/ a volatile modCount (which is written on modification and read on each itearyion, read is sorta free on x86, though).

Answer (score -1):

Probably a bit late answer, but Java 8 makes it much easier to remove elements from collection while iterating:

```
removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)
```

Removes all of the elements of this collection which satisfies the given predicate.